# jQuery Trigger not working correctly

Tags: jquery

Everything works on the page but the .not() even when i click on #s the animation still goes off! I want when the div id=s is clicked the animation not to go away but if you click any where else it will go back to normal. Jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/84Teg/

```
 $("div:not(#s)").click(function () {
        $("#re").animate({
            "margin-top": "0px"
        }, 800);
        $("#ret").animate({
            "margin-top": "0px"
        }, 800);
        $(".popu").animate({
            "margin-top": "0px"
        }, 800);
        $("#s").hide(200);
    });
```

Comment: what is going on there, its a bit confusing. Try expanding on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That's not the way we should write code. It's more fun and the result is more maintainable than you might think. We just need the info what is this all about... To give you a better guidance, not to leave you in the wrong path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `s` is the inner child of a div with a click event, you need to `stopPropagation()` else the event will bubble up and execute:

```
 $("div:not(#s)").click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
```